# Typescript generics keyof doesn't match type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this interface, that just stores a key of another interface (`modelKey`) and the value of that key (`value`):

```
interface ValueHolder<T, H extends keyof T> {
  modelKey: H;
  value: T[H];
}
```

Now I want to store the `horsePower` from the following model, with the matching type in a `ValueHolder`:

```
interface Car {
  id: number;
  horsePower?: number;
  date: Date;
};
```

This looks like this:

```
const test: ValueHolder<Car, keyof Car> = {
  modelKey: 'horsePower',
  value: 1000,
};
```

At this point no error happens and it would store the value fine. But you could also pass a value of type `Date`:

```
const test: ValueHolder<Car, keyof Car> = {
  modelKey: 'horsePower',
  value: new Date(),
};
```

Because for whatever reason the value can accept all types of any key in the model provided:

`(property) ValueHolder<Car, keyof Car>.value: string | number | Date | undefined`

---

How can I make the `value` key of the interface `ValueHolder` only accepts values of type `undefined | number`, if you provide the `modelKey` `horsePower`?

[Demo](https://tsplay.dev/NVgzBm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ValueHolder` second generic argument `H` allows all keys which in turn leads to allowing all values.

You need slightly modify your main utility type to make illegal state unrepresentable.

Consider this example:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type ValueHolder<T> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: {
    modelKey: Prop;
    value: T[Prop]
  }
}>

// type Test = {
//     modelKey: "id";
//     value: number;
// } | {
//     modelKey: "horsePower";
//     value: number | undefined;
// } | {
//     modelKey: "date";
//     value: Date;
// } | undefined
type Test = ValueHolder<Car>

interface Car {
  id: number;
  horsePower?: number;
  date: Date;
};

// ok
const test: ValueHolder<Car> = {
  modelKey: 'horsePower',
  value: 1000,
};

// error 
const test2: ValueHolder<Car> = {
  modelKey: 'horsePower',
  value: new Date(),
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2ErrW)

See `type Test`. `ValueHolder` creates a union of all allowed values. It iterates through each key and creates this interface {Prop:{modelKey:P, value:T[P]}}. Then `Values` obtains each object value `{modelKey:P, value:T[P]}` and makes a union of them.

**UPDATE**

> Thanks, works fine! What if I want that `T[Prop]` can only be of the type string? Is that also possible?

Yes it is. There is two ways to achieve it. You can allow `ValueHolder` only to receive objects where values are strings.

```js
type ValueHolder<T extends Record<string, string>> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: {
    modelKey: Prop;
    value: T[Prop]
  }
}>
```

Or, you can check inside iteration whether `T[Prop]` is string or not.

```js
type ValueHolder<T> = Values<{
  [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends string ? {
    modelKey: Prop;
    value: T[Prop]
  } : never
}>
```

Comment: Thanks, works fine! What if I want that `T[Prop]` can only be of the type `string`? Is that also possible?

Comment: @dewey made an update