# How to define a strongly coupled type depends on a defined object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```
type MyObjType = {
  a: number,
  b?: string
}

type Column<Data, DataKey extends keyof Data> = {
  accessor: DataKey,
  value: Data[DataKey]
}

const column: Column<MyObjType, keyof MyObjType>[] = [{
  accessor: 'a',
  value: "" // (property) value: string | number | undefined
}]
```

But I want the type of `value` to be number when `accessor` is 'a', value is `undefined | string` when `accessor` is 'b'

how to define the `Column` type to make it works?

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360665/typescript-generics-keyof-doesnt-match-type/70360794#70360794). Am I right ? See [example](https://tsplay.dev/wX2BJm)

Comment: @captain-yossarian Good catch captain! Just one small concern, we build `ValueHolder` by creating a temporary object type and getting all values type of it, is there a way to define this type directly? your answer is correct, just wondering if there's a better way

Comment: what do you mean directly? I don't think that there is a better way to do it (

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks for your feedback! I believe its the right one

Answer (score 0):

Got [Answer](https://tsplay.dev/wX2BJm) from @captain-yossarian